# Enum — это анти-паттерн? Почему?

Tags: c#, .net

Правда ли, что `enum`- это анти-паттерн и его всячески нужно избегать?

Если да, то почему?

Comment: Откуда у вас такая мысль появилась?

Comment: `enum- это анти-паттерн` - эта фраза просто смысла не имеет. Паттерн - это способ что то сделать, enum - это тип данных. Они никак не связаны между собой

Comment: @Regent коллега сказал, так опираясь на то, что статический класс со статическими полями лучше тем, что более гибко

Comment: @iluxa1810, интересно было бы узнать чем именно гибче, желательно с примерами кода

Comment: @iluxa1810 слова вашего коллеги конечно не лешены смысла([SKColors](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/binding/Binding/SKColors.cs)), но вот на практике это очень редко когда нужно.

Comment: Мне кажется, если вопрос сформулировать "В каких случаях следует использовать `enum`, а в каких наследование?", то он станет гораздо лучше и полезнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, это миф. Перечисление используется для представления определенной семантики - целочисленный тип с множеством именованных допустимых значений (хоть язык и позволяет присвоить перечислению любые значения, для этого требуется явное приведение, так что типобезопасность соблюдается). Класс с набором статических readonly-полей (или свойств) представляет другую семантику - тип, в котором некоторые значения имеют особый смысл, но другие значения тоже являются допустимыми.

См. например [Colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx) - цвет может принимать любые значения из непрерывного диапазона RGBA-последовательностей, но для ряда часто используемых сделаны константы.

Другое дело, что иногда enum используют как замену нормальной иерархии классов: вместо наследования с переопределением абстрактных методов пихают enum-поле и один большой спагетти-метод со switch. Это действительно можно считать "антипаттерном", так как от этого страдает читаемость кода и удобство работы с ним в IDE.

Связанный вопрос: [When are enums NOT a code smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/300080)

Comment: Т.е enum нужно использовать, если он не влияет ни на какую логику? Если от него начинает зависеть поведение, то надо использовать наследование с переопределением функционала в наследниках?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Скорее, нельзя использовать для разграничения логики на основе типа объекта (так как для этого есть специальное средство - наследование). Для разграничения логики на основе, скажем, текущего состояния объекта, использование enum + switch оправданно, и часто используется.

Comment: Хм, очень тонкая грань. Вот например, у меня есть фигура и я добавлю в нее свойство `enum` ТипФигуры, это плохо? А, скажем, для какой-нибудь кнопки и блока текста использовать enum в свойство `Alignment` - это нормально? Почему бы нам не инкапсулировать выравнивание в классах `LeftAlignment`, `CenterAlignment` и т.д., а свойство у кнопки сделать типа `AlignmentBase`?

Comment: Наверное, во втором случае наследованием вообще задачу не решить, т.к. выравнивание делает панель, в которой лежит кнопка и это ее поведение, поэтому его невозможно вынести в такие классы как `LeftAlignment` или `CenterAlignment`. У каждой панели будет своя реализация и, соответственно, свой switch

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, тонкая грань, но во втором случае действительно enum оправдано, так как типов контейнеров может быть много, а вариантов выравнивания - немного, и новые вряд ли появятся. Поэтому для разграничения логики на основе типа контейнера лучше использовать средства ООП, а на основе выравнивания - enum+switch.